# Why did Community approve a suggested edit while there is no proof of it?

Tags: support, bug, review, suggested-edits, community-user

From my understanding, the Community user will approve or reject a suggested edit if there was a concurrent edit, or someone in the review queue clicked `Improve & Edit` or `Reject & Edit`.

I found [a weird case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38768) just now, where the Community user apparently approved a suggested edit, while the suggested edit review log shows two users. There isn't an additional revision that could explain the concurrent editing.

The Community user approved, right?

[image: community approved]

... or didn't it?

[image: user approved]

As you can see, [no concurrent edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/243201/revisions).

What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edit wasn't *approved* by Community ♦, it was *credited as having been made by* Community ♦. Presumably because an anonymous user suggested it.

Comment: Ah, of course. Missed that totally. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is that the edit was "made" by the Community User, not that it was approved by it.

The edit was suggested by an anonymous user, and one of the [Community User's jobs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is to

> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Missed that.